# Can I use a control to change two scripting variables at once?

Tags: python, scripting, interface

I know I can create an integer or float value in a script and add a control on a panel to let me change that value. But that's one-dimensional. Is there any control I can put in a panel to allow me to change two variables in as if I'm dealing with two dimensions?

For example, let's say I have Text that I want to put on Plane. So once I've aligned Text so it's on the Plane, and Plane is on the Z Axis, I want to move Text by changing the values for the X and Y axes. I know I can do that in the window in Object Mode, but my understanding is that, while my script is running, I can't grab and move objects. I know I could put in two variables, each with its own control and change the X value or the Y value, but is there any kind of control that would let me change both X and Y at the same time?

(Alternatively, if I'm wrong, and it's possible to move objects while a script is running, and I can constrain the movement, within the script, to two dimensions, I'd accept that.)

The main purpose of this script is to make adding text to a plain and moving it around on the plain quick and easy (It's within the context of something bigger - just part of what the overall script is doing.) So I want to get text from the user, then, in the script, put it on the plane, then the user could use the controls or mouse to move it in place. Once it's in place, there's more to do, so I need to move the text and, after that, still do more with the text.

Comment: maybe i misunderstand you, but you could e.g. add a sphere and put in a driver for the x and y value of the text which will be driven by the x/y value of the sphere. So if you move just the sphere (one controller) you can change the x and y value (2 values) of the text....but i am pretty sure i misunderstood you...you for me...your text is not easy understandable.

Comment: @Chris: That's about it, but I think it'd be a circle, not a sphere - so if you slide left to right it'd change, say, the X value, and if you slide up and down, it'd change the other value. I am definitely open to editing and suggestions about making it more understandable!

Comment: The script hangs the UI, as Blender is single-threaded. You can work around it, for example you can assign the script to some kind of event, for example `context.window_manager.event_timer_add` to run it every few milliseconds or `bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add`. If you show what you do in your script, or a minified example, then it will be easier to answer the question.